# Какое регулярное выражение соответствует строке:

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Какой шаблон соответствует строке, которая состоит из символов a-z0-9._-"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^([a-z0-9."_-]+)$/
```

Comment: @MDJHD, вы кавычку забыли

Comment: @VenZell поправил, спасибо